# background-image url not working

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="dict"></div>
```

---

```
.dict {
    background-image: url("dict.png");    
}
```

This does not appear to work as I would like it to. It doesn't display an image? Can someone please explain why, and how I could fix it? Thanks

You can find this code active on http://www.zentriamc.com/test

Comment: I think you should give us a link to your web page or a link to jsfiddle. Plus, you did not describe well what happens to the image. We cannot see any problems merely by looking at the code above

Comment: Edited original post.

Comment: check that the path of your image is correct

Comment: Give some `height` to `.dict` as you don't have any content inside it. By default an empty block level element will take 100% available width and zero height.

Comment: +felixsturm Very unnecessary. Flagged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want your image as tiny icon in the background so that nobody could copy it, then you can do the following.

```
.dict {
   padding-left: 66px;
   background: url(dict.png) no-repeat left center; 
}
```

here i am assuming that your icon's size is 50 px and for left padding from that icon i added 16 px to it, so that your icon doesn't get covered by your content inside the div.

so it should give some effect like :

[image]

Comment: It works, but how would I like resize dict.png to 50px or something? If I try changing it to 50px, it just loads a small corner of the image.

Comment: you should better take a look at this tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: and do you exactly want your div to be width of 50px? if so, then resizing that image will save the day..

Comment: it seems you are confused with background and div. that background image will take all the width and height of the div to fill the background of the div, won't it?

Comment: Basically, I wanted dict.png to be a tiny icon thing, uncopyable. How would I do this? I needed it to be like 50px or something

Comment: i updated my answer., so you should better take a look at that