# CSS Background placement

Tags: css, web

```css
.container {
    width: 800 px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main {
    background: url(images/header_slice.jpg) repeat-x;
}
#main.container {
    background: url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
}
#sidebar h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #044055;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#sidebar ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #393838;
}
ul#subscribe li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 155px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    background: #d4d6d3;
    border: 1px solid #BEBDBD;
    padding: 15px 15px 30px 30px;
}
#sidebar h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #044055;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
#sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
#sidebar ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #393838;
}
ul#subscribe li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
ul#subscribe li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
ul#subscribe li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 35px;
}
li#rss {
    background: url(images/rss_icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
}
li#email {
    background: url(images/email_icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
}
li#twitter {
    background: url(images/twitter_icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
}
```

I was learning how to make a basic website from: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-and-code-your-first-website-in-easy-to-understand-steps--net-6062
The header background from the container isn't loading.

[image]

Also the the sidebar icons are being overlapped by the text. I tried adding padding in the sidebar anchor but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you're using external css file, the `background url should be (../folder/name)`. and the container with the background should have a defined height

Comment: could you please tell me the image path which you want to apply in background?

Answer (score 0):

fist have some padding to the left from your icon so you text won't overlap it and then for background say that it should appear on the left side , center vertically. I shown how to do with li for twitter

```
li#twitter {
   padding-left: 66px;
   background: url(your-icon-path.png) no-repeat left center; 
}
```

here i am assuming that your icon's size is 50 px and for left padding from that icon i added 16 px to it, so that your icon doesn't get covered by your content.

if you wish you could take a look at the answer that i gave someone previously [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264585/background-image-url-not-working/40264643#40264643)